# How can I charge an Android phone while it's controlling my 3D printer?

Tags: g-code

I am writing a G-code sender for Android, but I have hit a snag.
How can I prevent the phone from discharging while it sending G-code to the printer?

I have several Android phones and tablets and they have a micro USB OTG connector, which I can connect to my 3D printer using an adapter.
But it looks like OTG has this limitation - it can either accept power when in *Device* mode, or it can provide power in *Host* mode.  So, while in *Host* mode the phone can't be charged, so I can't do long prints, which seems like an unreasonable limitation.

Any ideas on how to solve this?

Comment: This question isn't really about 3D printing. The 3D printer isn't relevant to the question, it's just a question of whether a smartphone can charge while in USB OTG mode. Moreover, the specific phone in question is probably quite important to the answer.

Comment: I think this problem is specific to 3D printing, because it's a very unique use case.  3D printer must be connected to the phone for several hours.  In other use cases a person can transfer a file to a USB flash drive in just a few minutes, so a battery charging is not an issue.  Also it's not specific to the phone.  Every phone and tablet I have behaves the same for this matter.

Comment: The *answer* might be specific to the phone/tablet. Maybe some support it, maybe some don't,...

Comment: Ah, I see.  But even if there is only one phone that "support it" - that would be a solution.  I'll just buy that exact phone.  Thanks.

Comment: This can be Android device specific.  Can you edit your question to list the devices you have tried this on?

Comment: It looks like this special cable doesn't work on any of my OTG devices: Dragon Touch Y88X Plus, LenoTab, Kindle Fire 7" model SV98LN, KOSLAM 10 inch tablet.

Comment: P.S. But I have heard that it works for some other devices: Samsung i9300 Galaxy S 3, Nexus 4, Nexus 5, Nexus 6, Nexus 10.  I wonder if anyone have made a complete list?  Or is there an online database of devices that implement OTG standard properly?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See *elsewhere* on StackExchange:

- Electronics:

  - [Can an Android tablet serve as USB Host and be charged simultaneously through a single port?](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/34741/can-an-android-tablet-serve-as-usb-host-and-be-charged-simultaneously-through-a)
- Android Enthusiasts

  - [Using an OTG cable while charging](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/34227/using-an-otg-cable-while-charging)
  - [USB charging in host mode [duplicate]](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/28745/usb-charging-in-host-mode)

You certainly can charge whilst in host mode, but some re-wiring will be required.

From the SE.Electronics [link](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/34741/can-an-android-tablet-serve-as-usb-host-and-be-charged-simultaneously-through-a)

> Apparently it is possible to charge the Host-Device! -->
>   http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/USB_On-The-Go
>
> Under "OTG Micro Plugs" it says that a USB OTG cable with a 36.5 kΩ
>   resistor between Pin 4 (I suppose its pin 4) and Pin 5 allows you to
>   connect a B-Device (Slave) and (!) a Charger to the Smartphone/Tablet.
>   The Phone and the B-Device can be supplied by the external power
>   source.
>
> USB-Power Specifications:
>   http://www.usb.org/developers/devclass_docs/batt_charging_1_1.zip

and

> I just sifted through the docs because I didn't trust Wikipedia's implicit data on which of the three resistances I should use. Here you can find the official `Battery Charging v1.2 Spec and Adopters Agreement`: [usb.org/developers/docs/devclass_docs](http://www.usb.org/developers/docs/devclass_docs/) In this case you want 124kΩ, because you want the OTG device (=tablet) to be the A device (=host).

Here are the schematics:

[image: Post schema]

Comment: @Sergey - Welcome. Your app sounds interesting, btw.

Comment: Note that this can be device specific.  Not all android devices implement USB OTG and charging the same way.